# How do I reset Emacs keybindings to default?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I was unsetting the C-z quit shortcut in my Emacs. I accidentally made a typo, and somehow made it so that I couldn't capitalize the letter C. In an effort to try to restore this, I accidentally unset C-y, and then accidentally set it back to "undo" instead of "paste". Then I accidentally unset the letter "c" completely.

My Emacs is in a mess right now. How can I just reset these keys to their default commands?

For reference, I am running on EC2 with AMI 5.10. I also could not find an existing Emacs init file in any of the standard locations.

Comment: Did you try restarting Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "reset all the keys" command (and for numerous reasons it wouldn't make any sense to include one), but if you don't want to restart your existing instance, then do this:

1. Start a new, separate instance.
2. In that, ask Emacs what the key is bound to, using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>
3. Back in the original instance, rebind the key to that command (in the same keymap)

For the global keymap you can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `global-set-key`

More generally, evaluate the code `(define-key KEYMAP (kbd "KEY SEQUENCE") #'COMMAND)` for the KEYMAP name indicated in the *Help* buffer.  E.g. if I saw:

> C-y runs the command yank (found in global-map)

Then (because it's the global keymap) I could use *either* of these:

- `(define-key global-map (kbd "C-y") #'yank)`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `global-set-key` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-y</kbd> `yank` <kbd>RET</kbd>